# Overrite method from external or private class

Tags: java, maven

I have some method that use method from external library (mvn). So I cannot adit it. When Im trying override that method im getting:

> void is not public in *class; cannot be accessed error from outside
>   package 
>       dont have access to that external library

The question in how to override method from external class (library) that extends abstract class or class with private methods.

```
logout = new Class(arg1, arg2) { 
           @Override 
           public boolean ovMethod(){ 
               someMethod(true); 
}
```

Method ovMethod() from (external class, downloaded by maven) Class:

```
Class extends AbstractClass {

   public abstract class AbstractClass { 
        void someMethod(boolean arg) { 
        } 
   } 
}
```

Comment: In general, you don't override it, this is the whole point of encapsulation.  You _could_ try to use something like reflection, but that might be out of scope for your actual problem.

Comment: I hope you don't *really* have a class called `Class`, given that there's already `java.lang.Class`. A more realistic example would be useful. It's not clear what private method you're talking about either, given that you haven't shown any... It would really help if you'd provide a [mcve]. I doubt that Maven is relevant at all though.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, you shouldn't override methods that are not meant to be overridden. But as a last resort, if the method is package-private (a.k.a. default visibility) you can create your own class in the same package so it has permission to override the method:

```
package same.package_as.superclass;

public class MyClass extends Class {
    @Override
    void someMethod(boolean arg) {
        // custom implementation
    }
}
```